# Spring Flux: Properly catch exceptions on Mono.defer

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

That's my code:

```java
Flux.fromStream(ids.stream())
    .flatMap(id -> Mono.defer(() -> {
        String entity = myRepository.findById(id);
        return Mono.just(entity);
    })
)
.collectList()
```

I'd like to know how to properly catch each exception could be raised into `myRepository.findById`.

What about:

```java
Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.fromExecutor(...);
Flux.fromStream(ids.stream())
    .flatMap(id -> Mono.defer(() -> {
        String entity = myRepository.findById(id);
        return Mono.just(entity);
    }).subscribeOn(scheduler),
    10
)
.collectList()
.block();
```

Comment: Could you explain the reason for using Mono#defer in this situation? But to answer, you wrap your call in a try catch and return either the value or a Mono.error in the catch clause.

Comment: What do you mean by "properly catch each exception"? You can leave the code as-is and any exception that occurs will just be propagated out on the `block()` call which will terminate the stream - or if you want to suppress exceptions and continue the reactive stream, you can wrap the flatMap code in a try / catch. This code looks awfully suspicious though, it's not normal that you'd want to wrap blocking code in reactive constructs like this.

Comment: I need to process each id (get entity) in parallel in order improve my performance. The problem arises, when two `Mono.defer(...)` raise exception in "parallel"... Should I use `Mono.error()`?

Comment: It's still not clear what is your goal with error handling. Do you want to suppress them all? Do you want to let them pop out and abort the flow as soon as the first error happens? Do you want to try to execute all of them and throw an error only at the end if there were any?

Comment: i don't think you need to use defer inside flatmap, you can use `.onErrorMap()` function to handle errors, and also once a error propagate it will break the upstream chain n error will propagate to downstream

Comment: can i ask you why are you using Monos and Fluxes in a Spring MVC app that uses a blocking database driver. You will most likely not gain any performance comapared to using the plain `@Async` annotation in Spring MVC